# Drawable shape like this one

Tags: android

I want to draw a custom shape in the drawable xml file. So what would be code for it?

[image]

Comment: What you exactly wanna do???

Comment: see the image and i want draw that using xml

Comment: We are `not` a code writing service please post what you have tried so far!

Comment: @sidpal7747 check my answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="-22dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transperent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```